# mobile responsiveness for custom nav bar on bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, toggle, navbar

I've been searching for this fix for a while now. I'm y=using Bootstrap 3's awesomes responsiveness'  and everything was goingt fine until I tried have a collapse for the navbar when veiwd on mobile. The problem I'm having is that the button to toggle the nav does not seem to work at all. I thought that it might be something with the order of my   , but I just don't know...

This is my code--->

The stuff in the head tag ------->

```
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

         <!-- Custom tstylesheet -->
         <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

         <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
         <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>﻿
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">        </script>
```

---------<

```
<div class="container nav-border">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-inverse">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-list" id="navcol">
                <ul class="collapse nav-list navbar-collapse row" id="navcol">
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 active"><a href="index.html"> HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "><a href="about.html"> ABOUT AETHER</a></li>
                    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "><a href="spookfish.html"> SPOOKFISH</a></li>
                    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "><a href="services.html"> SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 "><a href="representation.html"> REPRESENTATION</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>    
    </nav>
</div>
```

----------------<

There isn't much in the stylesheet that target the nav except this
---------->

```
    .nav-border {
    border-top:thin solid #000;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.nav-list {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    border-top: solid #000;

}

.nav-list a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
```

----------<

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a lot of things wrong here...

- I don't see that you are including jQuery before the bootstrap.js file
- Looks like you are including the boostrap.js file twice... you only need one.
- You have the same id on two elements `navcol`. Ids must be unique.

And this is just the start... I would suggest taking the time to read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) over again.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/j0r68waw/1/) is a demo of what I think you are trying to do... compare it to what you have and try to understand the differences.

Comment: I have solved the problem. it was because of the use of those two elements. i cleaned up the code a little more too. Thank you for your input